# Let a', b', c' be the angle bisector of angle A,B, C in △ABC respectively. How to find the area of △ABC in terms of a',b',c'？

Tags: geometry

Let $a',b',c'$ be the length of angle bisectors from angle $A,B,C$ in $\Delta ABC$ respectively. Find area of $\Delta ABC$ in terms of $a',b',c'$.

[image: Diagram]

My approach:
$\Delta=1/2*a*a'*\sin(A/2+C)=1/2*b*b'*(B/2+C)=1/2*c*c'* \sin(C/2+A)
a/ \sin A=b/ \sin B=c/ \sin C = abc/2\Delta$
then I don't know how to simplify.
Or can it be simplified?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please note that here you are expected to show your work, otherwise it may seem to readers that you are looking for volunteers to do your homework for free! Also, I suggest you can search among previously asked questions. You might find that your question (or something similar to it) has already been answered. Good luck!

Comment: Saeed: Sorry I don't know the rules

Comment: This is not my HW. This is just a random question appeared in my mind.

Comment: I appreciate that you edited your post and added your approach. You can use the website's help for mathematical notation (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). This way your posts will be easier to read. Also, to add photos to your post, consider uploading files rather than giving external links.

Comment: sorry I do not have enough badge to add photo.

Comment: Hi @JackKoo, I edited your question to use latex formatting (putting all the math in between dollar signs). That is the customary way to present math symbols on this website.

Comment: thank you very much 

Comment: How can he deduce d^2=bc/(b+c)^2*((b+c)^2-a^2)?

Comment: Do he combine Stewart theorem and angle bisectors properties?